# Read a secure session cookie in Java

Tags: java, cookies, ssl, session-cookies

I have a secure session cookie set. I know it's there since I'm seeing it on the Chrome Developer Tools console and on [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) in Firefox.

When I try to read it from a [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) doing:

```
<%= session.getAttribute("cookie_name") %>
```

I always get `null`.

The page from which I'm trying to do this is:

- On the same domain in which the cookie is set (in this case 'localhost')
- Secured ([HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure))

How do I read the cookie value? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code I use.

```
public static String getCookieValue(HttpServletRequest request, String name)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        String result = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (!found && i < cookies.length)
                    {
                        if (cookies[i].getName().equals(name))
                            {
                                found = true;
                                result = cookies[i].getValue();
                            }
                        i++;
                    }
            }
        return (result);
    }
```

Comment: Does it count as a cookie or as a session value?

Comment: this is for a cookie that I set.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a clarification, I thought that you had to access session-lived cookies using the `session` object.

This is not like that, as Milhous pointed correctly, session-lived cookies are accessed like any other cookie